# Need help transforming a dataset from multiple rows to a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database (MySQL) that holds cost records for some of our customers (each customer has a different cost for items). Any given cost record has an effective date range (ie, the cost is valid for a given time frame). Here's some sample data:

```
Customer    ItemNumber    EffectDate    Counter    Cost
ABC123      ITEM101       2011-12-01          0    $1.00
ABC123      ITEM101       2011-12-10          0    $1.20
ABC123      ITEM101       2011-12-10          1    $1.25
DEF456      ITEM101       2011-11-15          0    $1.10
DEF456      ITEM101       2011-12-01          0    $1.12
```

To make some sense of that data, the "Counter" variable is the number of times it's been changed (this is from an antiquated accounting platform), and the date is the "Beginning Date" of the cost. So, ITEM101 for customer ABC123 will have a cost of $1.00 on 12/1/2011 and 12/8/2011, but starting 12/10/2011, will be $1.25 (would be $1.20, but the Counter has gone up - ie the cost is $1.25 now). I hope that makes sense.

What I'm trying to do is to get the data to come out as follows:

```
Customer    ItemNumber    EffectiveBegin    EffectiveEnd    Cost
ABC123      ITEM101       2011-12-01        2011-12-09      $1.00
ABC123      ITEM101       2011-12-10        2099-12-31      $1.25
DEF456      ITEM101       2011-11-15        2011-11-30      $1.10
DEF456      ITEM101       2011-12-01        2099-12-31      $1.12
```

Where 12/31/2099 is just a placeholder date for "Current".

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated!!

Comment: is the counter relevant to this query you are trying to build? it seems like all you care about is date ranges, right?

Comment: Well, the Counter is relevant, because with a given "Start Date", I only need the cost associated with the highest counter on that date. For example, ITEM101 for ABC123 on 12/10 has two records - Counter 0, Cost $1.20; and Counter 1, Cost $1.25. I only need Cost $1.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNTESTED: (read as: I likely have at least one logic error and 2-3 syntax errors)

```
Areas where there might be problems:

    1) B.effectiveDate-1 - Hoping B.EffectDate-1 when B.EffectDate is null 
       will retrun null so coalesce will return 12/31/2099.
    2) '12/31/2099' may need to be cast to date data type.
    3) Hoping mySQL supports date-1 to subtract 1 day.
    4) Replace "TABLE" with your table name
```

What it does:

```
1) Joins to self in order to get begin & End for Effective dates. Excludes same
   date entries.
2) subtracts 1 from B.effectdate when customer item has multiple entries to 
   get "End"
3) Only joins records where customer, item match AND B.Counter is the MAX counter. 
   (Key if multiple entires)
4) Uses cost from B if exists, otherwise uses A.
```

Without further ado:

```
    Select A.Customer, A.ItemNumber, A.EffectDate as EffectiveBegin, 
            coalesce(B.effectDate-1,'12/31/2099') as EffectiveEnd, 
            coalesce(B.cost, A.cost) as Cost
    FROM Table A
    LEFT JOIN Table B 
      ON A.Customer=B.Customer 
     and A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber 
     and A.EffectDate < B.EffectDate
     and B.Counter = (SELECT max(C.Counter) 
                      FROM Table C 
                      WHERE C.Customer = A.customer 
                        and C.ItemNumber = A.ItemNumber)
```

Basic overview:  Give me cost and date-1 of highest counter affiliated B record.  If no b record, use A record info for cost and 12/31/2099 for end date.

Comment: @thomas bosonix points out that I'm missing something are you sure you have the results you want?  or close enough you can get what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the query proposed by @xQbert, but it returns 5 rows for your sample data, not four as you requested.

Here is a tested query which returns four rows for your testing data:

```
select p.Customer, p.ItemNumber, p.EffectDate, coalesce(e.effectdate - interval 1 day, curdate()) EffectiveEnd, p.Cost
from (
  select customer, itemnumber, effectdate, max(counter) counter
  from prices
  group by customer, itemnumber, effectdate
) c
left outer join prices p
  on p.customer = c.customer 
  and p.itemnumber = c.itemnumber 
  and p.effectdate = c.effectdate
  and p.counter = c.counter
left outer join prices e
  on e.customer = p.customer 
  and e.itemnumber = p.itemnumber 
  and e.effectdate > p.effectdate
  and e.counter = p.counter
```